# Cardinality of largest set $S$ such that no two numbers in $S$ have a sum divisibly by $5$.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

> What is the largest subset of numbers from $1$ to $100$ such that no two numbers in the chosen subset will have a sum divisible by 5.

I started by considering the largest subset of numbers from $1$ to $5$, whose result can then by scaled up to the range $1$ to $100$.

I noted that in the set of residues of modulo 5, you can only choose at most two (1 and 2, for instance) since adding one more element would allow it to combine with itself and produce a sum $\equiv 0$ mod 5.

Thus, since you can only choose at most $2$ in every range of $5$, in the range from $1$ to $100$ you can get a maximum of $20 \cdot 2$ = 40. You can add in one more at the end (0, if we chose $1$ and $2$ as our repeating values) to get a total of $41$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that seems correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct, and basically counts as a proof as well.